# How do I get the requests module in python to have a clock time?

Tags: python

I'm trying to scrape some data off of a website that and print it to the console. However I've run into an issue in that the data I'm trying to scrape changes depending on the clock of the computer that's accessing it. Right now the data just isn't showing up at all when I send a request (the rest of the page is though). I think the issue is that the python request module isn't giving the page a clock time. If I'm correct is there a way to fix this and if not is there any other reason it might not be working?

My code so far if it helps:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests

while True:
    html_doc = requests.get('website removed for privacy').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.find(id='timeLeft').contents)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the python request module isn't giving the page a clock time." The webserver is probably using the time of the request, not data INSIDE the request, right?

Comment: It sounds *much* more likely that the data you're looking for is populated dynamically (using javascript) so you'll need selenium or some other browser automation to properly scrape it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm not sure, does the request module not run the JavaScript?

Comment: @AdamSmith that sounds like that's probably it. Thanks for the help.